# How to automatically start SQL Server Jobs

Tags: sql-server

**Problem**: In our company we do have a SQL Server which has to run a bunch of tasks every night.

So far, everything is scheduled, let's say Task 1 begins at 10pm, Task 2 at 10:30 and so on.

But unfortunately, not all the tasks always take the same time to run, so sometimes the tasks overlap (which slows them down, and therefor triggers a cascade of overlappings), or the server sits idle for some time, because one task finishes early, and the next one is scheduled 20 minutes later.

Sometimes a tasks gets stuck and needs to be killed manually.

What we are looking for is a software or a solution that:

- queues all the tasks (to minimize idle time)
- checks if one task overstepped a fixed time limit, within which it should have finished
- lets us put the task in interdependent groups, that will only trigger the next task when the previous one was successfully executed.

Since I'm not sure if I am making sense, I try to build an example:

Let's say we have 5 Groups of Tasks (A to E), each including 3 Tasks (1 to 3).

So we want to run task A1, then A2, then A3, then B1 and so on. Starting with A1 at a specific time each night, with the tasks starting directly after the previous one has finished.

We also want to specify for each task individually it's maximum amount of time it may run. (i.e. 20 Minutes for A1, 10 Minutes for A2, and so on) if this maximum is reached, the task shall be killed.

ALSO, if one task was killed, the latter tasks WITHIN THE SAME GROUP shall not be executed. But of course the next group shall start.

So if B2 exceeded it's allotted time, and was therefore killed, B3 shouldn't run, and the next Task should be C1.

I imagine that we're not the only ones with this problem, so I assume there to be solutions/software/code which addresses this problem?

Thank you kindly in advance for your help.

Comment: Sorry, product etc. suggestions are off-topic for StackOverflow

Comment: Okay, but maybe there is also a name for my problem, then I can Google myself? So do I have a "queue" problem, or am I looking for a task manager, or what? I am new to this field, and I am not sure which are the right keywords to look for.

Comment: Try Googling for "sql server batch scheduler". I did find https://www.jamsscheduler.com and https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com . Disclaimer: never used any of them myself.

Comment: You can try this data driven solution   https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6380/sql-agent-job-dependencies-with-table-driven-solution/